# Ajax call loads the complete page, does not allow for checking of returned data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

this is the HTML and JS I have:

```
</form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <button id="previewButton" class="btn btn-primary">Preview</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
<script>
    $("#previewButton").click(function () {
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "/Product/GetRules/",
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON"
        });

        request.done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });

        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            console.log(textStatus);
            alert("Request failed.");
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the controller code:

```
 public ActionResult GetRules()
 {
     ProductVM sVM = new ProductVM();

     sVM.ProductId = "test123";
     sVM.Rules = new List<string>() { ""20/2/15"", "10/2/15" };

     return Json(sVM, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

 }
```

and the Model:

```
public class ProductVM
{
    public string ProductId { get; set; }

    public List<string> Rules { get; set; }
}
```

It hits the controller on debugging and I can see the correct object in VS.
I placed an alert in the .done promise and it works by showing an alert with `[object object]`
so that means the AJAX call is working fine.

I want to look at the returned JSON so added the log statement but the browser is re-loading the page after the call and there is nothing in the console.

What am I doing wrong here?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The form is submitting because you need to cancel the default behaviour:

```
 $("#previewButton").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
```

> [**event.preventDefault()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)
>
> Description: If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form> <!-- </form> replaced with <form> -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <button id="previewButton" class="btn btn-primary">Preview</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
<script>
    $("#previewButton").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();/* Added prevention */
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "/Product/GetRules/",
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON"
        });

        request.done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });

        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            console.log(textStatus);
            alert("Request failed.");
        });
    });
</script>
```